# Font (from Google Fonts) not showing up on website

Tags: html, css, fonts

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);

/* CSS RESET */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* END CSS RESET */

body {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.header {
    padding: 0% 1% 0% 1%;
    width: 98%;
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}

.header .logo {
    padding-top:15px;
    height:45px;
    width:24%;
    float: left;
}

.header .logo img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height:30px;
}

.search {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.mb {
    display: none;
}

.search input[type="text"] {
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #dbdbdb;
    border: 1px solid #111111;
    border-radius: 9px;
    text-align: center;
}

.search input[type="text"]:focus {
    border: 2px solid #007AFF;
    outline: none;
    color: black;
}

.reglog {
    width: 24%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

.reglog button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #009CFF;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 1.5%;
    margin: 1%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    .search input[type="text"] {
        display: none
    }
    .mb {
        display: block;
    }
    body {
        font-family: 'Raleway'
    }
}
```

That's my CSS. I have tried linking it through file, through HTML, nothing works. This is the only CSS file. I'm really running out of ideas here, everything worked fine before. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Is your internet connection blocking the Google Font? Try going to the CSS file in your browser (go to https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway) and see if it loads that way.

Comment: it is working I just tested https://jsfiddle.net/nnwpwf6p/

Comment: Seems like your code is working fine, maybe it's the caching of CSS? try to update the version like this: `style.css?ver=2`

Comment: @AppleCrazy I can open it fine: http://i.imgur.com/ywHIzpl.png.

Comment: @flux that ain't working either, smashing my computer.

Answer (score 1):

As the google fonts while including in css file like this

`@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,400italic)`;

and not be as

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the link in the html's head section, not in the css. Like this:

```
<head>
<link rel="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
</head>
```

Then, you can call your font-family in the stylesheet.

Comment: You can import it from CSS if you want it'll work, so linking it from HTML is not necessary, but yeah, I've tried that too, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, something broke when I was making VirtualHosts on Apache, I have no idea how, disabling VHosts and returning to my standard URL scheme fixed the problem. Weird..

Anyways, thank you all that tried to help, I appreciate it.
Farewell!